# What type of chakra element does the Aburame clan possess?

Tags: naruto

Among the five basic elements of chakra (earth, water, wind, lightning and fire), what type of chakra does the Aburame clan possess to control insects at their will?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It very well could be a Kekkai Genkai, a ninja ability that is genetic or passed down by nature genetically, i.e. Bakugan, or Shadow Weaving (the Nara Clan).  The make up of these abilities is not known and is really a family secret only known to those within the clan.

Comment: Hidden Jutsu are definitly not Kekkai Genkai, its mearly that their secrets are hidden from everyone else. Most of them are Yin and Yang though, including the Nara clan, as all chakra manipulation is of the 5 elements, or yin/yang, or of pure chakra itself. That being said, the Insect do eat raw chakra regardless of its affinity, so they might not even need a nature. All their ninjutsu are insect related

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it matters. The insects live under their skins in symbiosis with their host. The shinobi and the insects both benefit from this: the insects feed on their host's chakra (and I don't think they care about its type), and the host can use ninjutsu involving the insects.

Note that ninjutsu must not necessarily be bound to a specific element. For example, Shadow Clone Technique is a ninjutsu which can be used by a lot of shinobi with different chakra types. Therefore, I think that Aburame clan members can have any chakra type.

Comment: This. The bugs that consume chakra can consume chakra of any nature, as seen in the series.

Answer (score 5):

Chakra is based on In (Yin) and Yo (Yang). If both come together, Seishitsuhenka can be applied to the chakra. Some techniques (like Kagebunshin no jutsu) only work with manipulating In and Yo (only if both are combined 1:1, the "normal" chakra(like used in Rasengan) is created). Because Kikaichū no Jutsu and the other Jutsus needs no signs, no chakra is manipulated. They are only simple techniques to be used with the knowledge of insects.

All in all, it's never shown that members of the Aburame-clan don't use Seishitsuhenka.

Comment: Yes, and see [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/485/what-constitutes-as-an-yin-yang-yinyang-element-technique) for further info on yin yang techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The Aburame Clan doesnt have a specified affinity for an element chakra nature. But I believe most would have elemental chakra natures that compliment their clan's ability, such as Earth and Water. They probably incorporate Yang release as well because their Beetles are given life.